# Apply android.graphics.Matrix transformation to an Open GL ES shader

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, opengl-es

I am currently using a 4x4 matrix to convert from "pixel" coordinates to OpenGL ones, my scene is full screen so my screen matrix looks like this:

```
2f / width, 0f, 0f, 0f,
0f, -2f / height, 0f, 0f,
0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
-1f, 1f, 0f, 1f
```

I am then mapping this matrix as "uScreen" in the vertex shader in this way:

```
uniform mat4 uScreen;
attribute vec2 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexPos;
varying vec2 vTexPos;
void main() {
    vTexPos = aTexPos;
    gl_Position = uScreen * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And draw using this fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexPos;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPos);
}
```

So let's say that now i have some transformation (just scale and translate and 2D rotations) done with a 3x3  android.graphics.Matrix how can i apply these transformations to this shader? I have tried mapping it to a mat3 in the vertex shader and do "uScreen * uTransform * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0)" but its not working.

**Update**
I have tried to map the Canvas Matrix to the shader in this way:

```
uniform mat4 uScreen;
uniform mat3 uTransform;
attribute vec2 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexPos;
varying vec2 vTexPos;
void main() {
    vTexPos = aTexPos;
    gl_Position = uScreen * mat4(uTransform) * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
};
```

And now its properly scaling but translation is not working

Comment: Try uScreen * (uTransform * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0)) to see if this fixes your issue. Note that this is actually a big change from maths perspective.

Comment: I figure there's a good reason why you use `android.graphics.Matrix`, and not `android.opengl.Matrix`?

Comment: @MaticOblak i dont understand the difference but will try

Comment: @RetoKoradi i am also presenting the same scene in a canvas so i'd like to share the matrix between the 2

Comment: The matrix multiplication order does matter and A*B does not equal B*A in most cases. Think of it as if turning A/B/C to A/(B/C) with floats. That is a huge difference.

Comment: @MaticOblak True, A*B is not the same as B*A. But (A*B)*C is mathematically equivalent to A*(B*C), which is the situation in this case.

Comment: I think you might want to rethink on that one a bit :)

Comment: @MaticOblak "uScreen * (uTransform * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0))" does not work however "uScreen * mat4(uTransform) * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0)" is properly scaling but not translating, any tip?

Comment: Is the row/column order correct on your matrix? You might need to transpose the matrix since this is on android...

Comment: @MaticOblak matrix is this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html how can i transpose that?

Comment: @MaticOblak found the solution!! its enough to use the android graphics Matrix.mapPoints() method on the aPosition vector!!